# How to skip robotests testing when building aosp modules?

Tags: android, android-source, robolectric

I'm building aosp-12 ROM for my pixel phone.
But I found most time was consumed on runing Robolectric tests.

For example:

```
host Robolectric: RunSettingsRoboTests3
    1:46 host Robolectric: RunSettingsRoboTests0
    1:46 host Robolectric: RunSettingsRoboTests1
    1:46 host Robolectric: RunSettingsRoboTests2
    1:46 host Robolectric: RunSettingsRoboTests3
```

Can I configure to skip them?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a nearly identical question recently.

[How to disable building and running AOSP tests when building with mm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096077/how-to-disable-building-and-running-aosp-tests-when-building-with-mm)

The solution was to set the following make variable when starting your build:

```
m DISABLE_ROBO_RUN_TESTS=true
```