# How to disable building and running AOSP tests when building with mm?

Tags: android-source

In Android 13 when I use `mm` to build a specific module such as `packages/apps/Settings` the build system is building tests and running robolectric to execute host-side tests along with building the app itself.

I just want to build the module (in this case Settings) without running the tests since that adds considered time to the development process. How do I skip running the robolectric tests when using `mm`?

Furthermore in the case of Settings using `mm` also installs an app named `SettingsRoboTestStub.apk` into the system.img and now the system won't boot due to permissions errors. I have to manually delete `SettingsRoboTestStub.apk` and rebuild the `system.img` to get it to boot which is inconvenient so in additional to not running the tests I would also like to not build any tests as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command disables running the robolectric tests and specifies the particular module in the specified directory to build which avoids building test modules.

```
mmm DISABLE_ROBO_RUN_TESTS=true packages/apps/Settings:Settings
```

I wasn't able to specify an individual module using `mm` but with `mmm` it works. This is mentioned when running `hmm`:

```
- mm:         Builds and installs all of the modules in the current directory, and their
              dependencies.
- mmm:        Builds and installs all of the modules in the supplied directories, and
              their dependencies.
              To limit the modules being built use the syntax: mmm dir/:target1,target2.
```